# Can a report have multiple record source?

Tags: ms-access

I have different queries and I want to include certain columns from each query in my report. I seem to be able to only choose one query for the record source. I want to be able to sum the columns that I chose and display on the report.

I tried to use expression builder and connect all the query using inner join but I still get error. I also tried to create a query that takes in all the columns that I want and then set the records source based on that query. However, each query has different criteria that gives me a certain result. For example, query1 gives me 237 records based on its criteria and query2 gives me 501 records based on its criteria. When I create another query to take in the columns that I want for each criteria, I get 738 records and when I used the sum function and then display the result I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need **UNION ALL**
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/union-operation-aa310e10-282b-4693-b6e3-2a2efdd87f1d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
Use union query as source for another query like this:

```sql
SELECT GroupCol, Sum(SumCol) AS TotalSum
FROM (
  SELECT SomeColumn AS GroupCol, ColumnForSum AS SumCol
  FROM query1

  UNION ALL
  SELECT AnotherColumn, AnotherColumnForSum
  FROM query2
) AS subquery
GROUP BY GroupCol
```